# Java - Auto Completion in IntelliJ for new object

Tags: java, intellij-idea, constructor, autocomplete

I'm using IntelliJ for writing Java programs and I want to write the line:

```
ClassName objectName = new ClassName(...)
```

I'm looking for an auto-completion feature (like sout+TAB, psvm+TAB) that once I write:

> ClassName objectName =

IntelliJ completes automatically the rest of the line:

> new ClassName(...)

Do you know such an auto-completion ?

Comment: Just type "new" - IntelliJ will do the rest.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using `Ctrl + Space`. That will give you the most likely completion to your statement.

Answer (score 1):

IntelliJ's autocomplete pops up by default every time you start typing something, with its best guess as the top selection, and pressing enter will use the currently selected suggestion. The key sequence `n, enter, shift+C, enter` should result in the desired autocompletion.

`Ctrl + Space` will bring up autocomplete without typing something first, but I just tried it and `new` is not its first guess for an object assignment on my computer. It does get the constructor right if you type `new` first, though.